# How to save RAM when dealing with very large python dict?

Tags: python, database, dictionary

I have a billion-level key-value pairs and need to create a look-up table for them. I currently uses the native python `dict`, however, it seems to be very slow when adding the pairs into the dict and consumes lots of RAM (several hundred GB). The option I need is to 1) add every pair into the dict and 2) lookup for a few million times. Are there any recommended ways I should take to meet the requirement? I have a machine with a few hundred Gigabyte memory (but not sufficient to store everything in-memory) and a good amount of CPU cores.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "slow"? How did you measure it? How much exactly is "lots of" RAM?

Comment: Consider the size of your RAM vs the size of your disk(s). That's why a database writes to disk blocks and uses a BTree to access what you need as you query it. You need a database

Comment: You are going to have to provide way more details about your use-case if you want any sort of useful advice.

Comment: at least tell us what the usage pattern of that dict is: what data are you looking up? how often etc...

Comment: Needs to use a database is correct but even with that, the amount of data in there hes going to have to do a look up for things in chunks rather than the whole thing at once.

Comment: @JacobIRR Thanks! I have updated the question. Could you take a look?

Comment: @D.Sanders Do you have any recommended database?

Comment: The database depends on your use case. An answer pointed out SQLite for instance, but there are others. What are you doing?

Comment: If your keys are bytes that are matched exactly and the values are bytes, then LevelDB and the like KV stores are more suited and efficacious than SQLite for that.

Answer (score 2):

If this data is not shared between machines (and if it's in memory with a `dict` I don't think it is) then I would recommend using a local SQLite database.

Python has an [internal library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) for interacting with SQLite which is fast (written in C), stores data to disk (to save RAM) and is available almost everywhere.